# Google Search Console Limit for Fetching

Tags: google, google-search-console

I want to ask this cause I always notice it. Is the "Fetch as Google" now limited to 12 URLs per day? I always got an error after 12 "Request indexing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quota is now somewhere around 10 fetches:

*"You have a daily quota of 10 fetches. When you are approaching your limit, you will see a notification on the page."*
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en